# UI Bootstrap Datepicker needs second click to update month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using UI Bootstrap Datepicker. When I click to choose the next month, the datepicker itself updates correctly but the month name does not (see picture 1 and 2).

However, once I have chosen a date, the updating the month name works just fine.
Only the first time this problem occurs.

I use $templateCache to inject the datepicker, which looks like this:

```
<button type="button"
                          class="btn btn-default datepickerButton dateButton"
                          datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                          ng-click="clickCalendar($event,$index,0)"
                          name="date"
                          ng-model="example.date"
                          is-open="example.open"
                          ng-change="selectDate($index)"
                          show-weeks="false"
                          min-date="Datepicker.getMinDate()"
                          max-date="Datepicker.getMaxDate()"
                          datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                          show-button-bar="false">
                    {{example.date|changeDateFormat}}</button>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use `bootstrap.js` with the `angular-ui-bootstrap.js` library?

Both libraries are working with the same events. If is this your case, remove the `bootstrap.js` library.

Comment: sorry, my bad. Of course I only use angular-ui-bootstrap